# HTAccess ModRewrite not working for directory to file

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule in htaccess to point a directory at a file, I keep getting 404 errors in return. I should mention, the main site is a wordpress site and I'm trying to redirect one of it's url's internally for a page with a trailing folder to another url.

For instance, this is the url for the wordpress page:

`/homes-for-sale-details/4420/217007490/177/`

The landing page I'm trying to create within that url is:

`/homes-for-sale-details/4420/217007490/177/Fb-landing-page`

So I did this:

```
RewriteRule /homes-for-sale-details/4420/217007490/177/Fb-landing-page/(.*)$ /propertylisting1/index.php?success=$1
```

No go, I get a 404 error in return. The wordpress page still work, but this won't.

Right now this new rule is placed **after** wordpress' own rewrite:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I've also tried placing it before wordpress' rewrite and it breaks all my wordpress pages.

Answer (score 0):

I had it in the wrong place, after much testing I found out if I place this rewrite before the `RewriteCond` statements, it works, and it doesn't brake other Wordpress rewrites.

So the final is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^homes-for-sale-details/4420/217007490/177/Fb-landing-page(.*)$ propertylisting1/index.php?success=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```